# How to display components horizontally with CSS

Tags: html, css, vaadin

I'm using the Vaadin CssLayout API for the first time here's what i want to get:

[image]

Here's what i'm getting:

[image: current result]

Here's my code :

```
    footerCssLayout = new CssLayout();
    footerCssLayout.addStyleName("my-panel-theme");

    footerCssLayout.setWidth(SIZE_100_PERCENT);

    footerCssLayout.setMargin(false, true, false, true);

    totalLabel.setWidth("50%");
    totalAmountLabel.setWidth("50%");

    footerCssLayout.addComponent(totalLabel);
    footerCssLayout.addComponent(totalAmountLabel);
```

So i need to put the 2 fields in the same line. I thought that the fields will be put horizontally after reading the CssLayout vaadin specification:

> The display attribute of CssLayout is inline-block by default, so the components are laid out horizontally following another. CssLayout has 100% width by default. If the components reach the width of the layout, they are wrapped to the next "line" just as text would be. If you add a component with 100% width, it will take an entire line by wrapping before and after the component.

Here's the [CssLayout Vaadin specification document](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-csslayout.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
totalLabel.addStyleName("myStyle")
totalAmountLabel.addStyleName("myStyle");
```

Then in css:

```
.myStyle {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```